# Why my timer be reset after closing application?

Tags: java, android, service

i have a timer that shows how much time left to allow the user to play that again.
i realized that a service can do that for me.so i create a one with **START_STICKY** tag in **separate process**. and use a Receiver To get results..is that work fine. **but when i closing application service will be restart and everything start from beginning time...**

> Question is : How do I prevent to the restart the service or another?
>   way to fix this problem ?!

ty.regards.

> my activity:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity{

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();;
   }
   public static void StartService(Context context,int globalTime,int localTime){

    Intent i= new Intent(context,Services.class);       
    i.putExtra("value", localTime);
    i.putExtra("value2", true);
    context.startService(i);
   }

}
```

> my Reciver:

```
    public class Reciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    int defaultValue = -1;
    Toast.makeText(context,String.valueOf(intent.getIntExtra("value", defaultValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

> my Service:

```
public class Services extends Service {

int id;
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    alarm();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

   id = startId;
   maxTimerValue = mainIntent.getIntExtra("value", 0);

if(currentTimerValue < maxTimerValue){
        currentTimerValue++;    
        BroadCatster();
    }else{
        currentTimerValue = 0
    }
 }
}
public void alarm(){

    Intent i = new Intent(this, Services.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, 1000, pi);

}

public void BroadCatster(){

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Reciver.class);
    intent.setAction("RECIVER_FILTER");
    intent.putExtra("value", currentTimerValue);
    this.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

}

> MainFest

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.Reciver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="RECIVER_FILTER" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false"
    android:name="com.example.Services"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:process=":Service">
</service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no perfect way to prevent your service from being stopped. START_STICKY does not mean Android will not kill the service. Android may still kill the service if there is a resource crunch, STICKY will only help than OS may restart the service once resource crunch is gone.

So the is basic issue is that you are assuming service will never be killed and your time keeping is relying on that. It would be better to store last played time in a preference or SQLlite (or put it in bundle in onSaveInstance state) and read it from there each time you are in onStartCommand. Off course you will need to handle user time changes on which there are many threads on stack overflow which you can refer to

Answer (score 1):

Add this on your Service's onCreate

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
            .setContentTitle("Your App")
            .setContentText("")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

startForeground(1111, notification);
```

Comment: yes startForeground or create a Toast always prevent to restart the service if  the service run in separate process. your idea is working but i dont want show notification becaouse is always on user nerves :(

Comment: i try to get log but icant because java is a native plugin for me and i dont use it Directly ...anyway i belive somthing wrong with NotificationCompat because when i use Notification is work fine. my android version is 4.4.2 and my phone is s4..

Comment: yes Notification is working .but i dont want to show anything...and NotificationCompat isnt work for me...

Answer (score 0):

@mr.bug I don't have any idea about 'service' but i can suggest you a logic for your timer just save the start time in shared preference or whatever which is convenient for you, when your application start again that time take the differences of start time and current time.

Comment: ty. yes before i do such a thing. i save the curent timer and is work fine. but I came to do a better job and  see what is you see...